# My registeration page isn't checking the database to see if username has been taken

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a query that would check if username has been taken but it only stores the form data into the database even if the username already exists

```
<?php  

$db= new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'mytrackz');


$query= "SELECT * FROM users ";
$result2= mysqli_query($db, $query);
$user= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);




if (isset($_POST['regbutton']))
  {
    $username= $_POST['username'];
    $email= $_POST['email'];
    $password= $_POST['password'];

    $sql= "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password')";

    $result= mysqli_query($db, $sql);

    if ($user) {
    if ($user == $username){
        echo "Username already exists";
    }elseif($result){
        echo "Registeration Successful";
    }else{
        echo "Registeration unsuccessful";
    }
}
}
```

?>

Comment: Sounds as if you've solved your own problem. In any case your database table should have the username set as a unique field, and it will throw a trappable error if you try to insert a new row with the same username as one that already exists.

Comment: You don't check if the user name exists, you just select from the users table.

Comment: How do i go about it?

Answer (score -1):

1:
when you do '$query= "SELECT * FROM users "' you are getting all records in your table without any filter by user.

2:
afeter check the post in 'if (isset($_POST['regbutton']))' you are inserting the value without check in database.

3: 'if ($user == $username){
        echo "Username already exists";' you are checking a single value agains an array of objects from database;

To fix it:

```
<?php  
$db= new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'mytrackz');
if (isset($_POST['regbutton']))
  {
    $username= $_POST['username'];
    $email= $_POST['email'];
    $password= $_POST['password'];

    $query= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
    $result2= mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $user= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);

    if ($user['username'] == $username){
        echo "Username already exists";
    }else{
        $sql= "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES ('$username','$email', '$password')";
    $result= mysqli_query($db, $sql);

    }

}
```